# Kibana grok filter: Expected 'a' instead of 'i'

Tags: logstash, kibana

I have begun building a filter that will ultimately pull out certain key value pairs logged via dropwizard.
The message I want is in kibana but when I add a filter to use grok I get

*Expected 'a' instead of 'i'*

```
filter {
  if ([message] ~= "METRICS") {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}%{CRON_ACTION}%{JAVACLASS}%{SPACE}%{SYSLOG5424PRINTASCII}%{SPACE}.*"}
    }
  }
}
```

I doubt there is anything wrong with the filter, so maybe there is a kibana config issue?

thanks

Comment: Where is the error coming from? Logstash or kibana? Could you also post the whole output where you found the `Expected 'a' instead of 'i'` and perhaps the whole logstash configuration if the error is coming from there.

Comment: kibaba search when I filter on the message.
true, I could do this in logstash before it is sent to elasticsearch, but for now I want to do this in kibana.
Otherwise I could use a filter with a regex instead of grok, but surely grok is a plugin in kibana.